# android calendar should event id be a constant value?

Tags: android, calendar

I'm using an application that reads calendar events from the calendar.

Using the content provider, I'm reading the event details including the event id from INSTANCES.EVENT_ID on 
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/CalendarContract.Instances.html#EVENT_ID.

In some cases it appears that although I haven't modified the calendar event or any of its attributes, after a while I'm getting a different event id.
I found no documentation of this. Can I not assume that when retrieving a calendar event, its event id will not change?